# How can I convert JPAQuery object, which involves joins, to Predicate?

Tags: querydsl

My query looks like this -

```
            @Override
            public Page<Country> findPaginatedCountries(String country, Optional<String> status, Pageable pageable) {

                QCountry qCountry= QCountry.someObject;
                QActiveCountry qActiveCountry = QActiveCountry.activeCountry;

               JPAQuery jpaQuery = new JPAQuery(entityManager);

                QueryBase queryBase = jpaQuery.from(qCountry).innerJoin(qActiveCountry).fetch()
                        .where(qCountry.codeLeft.country.upper().eq(country.toUpperCase()))
                        .where(qCountry.codeRight.country.upper().eq(country.toUpperCase()));



                if(status.isPresent()){
                    queryBase = queryBase.where(qActiveCountry.id(qCountry.active.id))
                            .where(qActiveCountry.status.upper().eq(status.get().toUpperCase()));
                }
.......}
```

Can I write a Predicate instead, which would result in the same response?

```
 Predicate predicate= qCountry.id.eq(qActiveCountry.id).and(qCountry.codeLeft.country.upper().eq(country.toUpperCase())).and(qCountry.codeRight.country.upper().eq(country.toUpperCase()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Seems you are using Spring Data. Just create a new repository interface, or extend an existing JPARepository type interface with QueryDslPredicateExecutor like:

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long>, 
QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Country>
```

Now you can just pass your predicate like:

```
Predicate countryExpression= qCountry.id.eq(qActiveCountry.id).and(qCountry.codeLeft.country.upper().eq(country.toUpperCase())).and(qCountry.codeRight.country.upper().eq(country.toUpperCase()));
CountryRepository.findAll(countryExpression, pageable);
```